# My @inbook does not shows the editor and the title of the book?

Tags: citing

I am trying to cite a chapter of a book. However, the output does not include the title of the book and the editor name.

```
@inbook{embrechts_mcneil_straumann_2002,
place={Cambridge},
title={Correlation and Dependence in Risk Management: Properties and Pitfalls},
DOI={10.1017/CBO9780511615337.008}, 
booktitle={Risk Management: Value at Risk and Beyond}, publisher={Cambridge University Press},
author={Embrechts, Paul and McNeil, Alexander J. and Straumann, Daniel},
editor={Dempster, M. A. H.Editor}, 
year={2002},
pages={176–223}}
```

The output is:

*Embrechts, P., A. J. McNeil, and D. Straumann2002.Correlation and Dependence in Risk Management: Properties and Pitfalls, P. 176–223.Cambridge University Press.*

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openright]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{nth}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\begin{document}
\cite{embrechts_mcneil_straumann_2002}.
\bibliographystyle{humannat}
\bibliography{mynew}
\end{document}
```

Please note that I am using a `.bib` file to store my `.bib` references. Also, I am writing a Ph.D. thesis as separated chapters.

Any help, please?

Comment: Use `@incollection` instead of `@inbook`. Note that `place` won't be recognised by most styles, you probably want `address`. Your `editor` field should probably read `editor={Dempster, M. A. H.},` the `Editor` in `Dempster, M. A. H.Editor` seems like a copy-and-paste error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The go-to type for chapters in collection works is `@incollection`. The difference between `@incollection` and `@inbook` is that an `@incollection` usually has an `author` (of the chapter) and and editor (of the `booktitle`, the editor will amongst other things be responsible for compiling the different papers into one volume), but an `@inbook` normally does not need an editor since the `author` is the author of the entire book (monograph) and with it the chapter (here the `author` has (co-)written the entire book).

```
@incollection{embrechts_mcneil_straumann_2002,
  address   = {Cambridge},
  title     = {Correlation and Dependence in Risk Management: Properties and Pitfalls},
  DOI       = {10.1017/CBO9780511615337.008}, 
  booktitle = {Risk Management: Value at Risk and Beyond},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  author    = {Embrechts, Paul and McNeil, Alexander J. and Straumann, Daniel},
  editor    = {Dempster, M. A. H.}, 
  year      = {2002},
  pages     = {176–223},
}
```

Note also that I changed `place` to  `address` and removed the superfluous `Editor` in the `editor` field.