# How can I change the way/style the Editor is displayed in biblatex @inbook?

Tags: biblatex

I want to cite a chapter in a multi-authored book with `@inbook` in the way:

> [1] A. Fischer, W. Dudzinski, B. Gleising, P. Stemmer, in *Triboanalytics* (Eds: M. Dienwiebel, M.-I. de Barros), Springer, Berlin, Germany **2018**, Ch. 2.

But I have no idea how to get the editors in the form (Eds. names) and the chapter from "chap.", to "Ch."

With my code , I get:

> [1] A. Fischer, W. Dudzinski, B. Gleising, P. Stemmer, in *Triboanalytics*, ed. by M. Dienwiebel, M.-I. de Barros, Springer, Berlin, Germany **2018**, chap. 2.

My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  style = numeric,
  backend=biber,   
  autolang=hyphen, 
  sorting=none,    
  maxbibnames=99,
  doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,
  giveninits=true,
  date=year,
  punctfont=true,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space} % replaces . with , 
\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\space} %removes : after in
\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\mkbibbold{#1}} %write date in bold
\DeclareFieldFormat{parens}{#1} 

\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
\title{Test title}
\section{Introduction}
Just some example text~\cite{Fischer2018}.
\medskip
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The references.bib-file:

```
@inbook{Fischer2018,
   author = {Fischer, A. and Dudzinski, W.  and Gleising, B.  and Stemmer, P.},
   title = {Analyzing Mild- and Ultra-Mild Sliding Wear of Metallic Materials by Transmission Electron Microscopy},
   booktitle = {Triboanalytics},
   editor = {Dienwiebel, M. and de Barros, M.-I.},
   publisher = {Springer},
   address = {Berlin, Germany},
   pages = {29-59},
   year = {2018},
   type = {Book Section},
   chapter = {2}
}
```

Maybe someone can help me to change "ed. by" to "(Eds. names)" and "chap." to "Ch." within the bibliography.

Comment: You should always provide a full but minimal example others can just copy and play with as is. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that, that makes it a lot easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

For most intents and purposes (i.e. when you just use `editor` and not `editora`...`editorc` and friends), it should be enough to redefine the `byeditor+others` bibmacro a little.

The entry in question would normally be an `@incollection` and not an `@inbook`, so I changed that as well (see for example [My @inbook does not shows the editor and the title of the book?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/450516/35864)).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  style = numeric,
  backend=biber,   
  autolang=hyphen, 
  sorting=none,    
  maxbibnames=99,
  doi=false, isbn=false, url=false,
  giveninits=true,
  date=year,
  punctfont=true,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\setunit{\addspace}%
     \printtext[parens]{%
       \bibsentence
       \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
       \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
       \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
       \clearname{editor}%
       \newunit}}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space} % replaces . with , 
\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\space} %removes : after in
\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\mkbibbold{#1}} %write date in bold

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  chapter  = {Ch\adddot},
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Fischer2018,
   author = {Fischer, A. and Dudzinski, W.  and Gleising, B.  and Stemmer, P.},
   title = {Analyzing Mild- and Ultra-Mild Sliding Wear of Metallic Materials by Transmission Electron Microscopy},
   booktitle = {Triboanalytics},
   editor = {Dienwiebel, M. and de Barros, M.-I.},
   publisher = {Springer},
   address = {Berlin, Germany},
   pages = {29-59},
   year = {2018},
   type = {Book Section},
   chapter = {2}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Just some example text \autocite{Fischer2018}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: A. Fischer, W. Dudzinski, B. Gleising, and P. Stemmer, in Triboanalytics (Eds.: M. Dienwiebel and M.-I. de Barros), Springer, Berlin, Germany 2018, Ch. 2.]

Comment: Thank you very much, you have solved my problem. :D

Comment: @TimoEnchen If the answer solved your question, you may want to consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark icon on the top left to show that the issue is resolved. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.